# How is Metamask able to interact with Ethereum if it doesn't require running a full node?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, wallets, full-node

How is Metamask able to interact with Ethereum if it, Metamask, doesn't require running a full node? Does Metamask use any third-party service for it? If so, is this the only way - to use a third-party service, if one doesn't run his own full node?

The question is for other browser or addon wallets out there as well, for other blockchains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, Metamask uses Infura (https://infura.io/faq, search for 'Metamask') node provider.

In order to access the blockchain, you need access to some node. You can either run your own, or use an existing node - such as from a node service provider.

You don't have to run a full node to get access to the blockchain. Depending on your node client, there are other, lighter, node synchronization types. For example Geth has *light* and *fast* types.

Comment: What's the size of a full node of light and fast types  of Geth ?

Comment: It depends. If you start fast node now, it will be very small, but will continue to get bigger at the same rate as full node. Unsure about light.